# FE_INVALID generation, signedness of NaNs

Tags: x86, floating-point, x86-64, nan, amd-processor

I did the following calculations on my AMD Zen1 CPU (the results are the same with my Phenom II CPU) and decoded the binary represention of the generated `NaN` to detect whether it is negative or positive. And I `fetestexcept( FE_INVALID )` after that (having cleard the exceptions before).

```
0.0  / 0.0  = -QNaN, invalid
0.0  / Inf  = 0.0
0.0  / QNaN = +QNaN, invalid
0.0  / SNaN = +QNaN
1.0  / QNaN = +QNaN, invalid
1.0  / SNaN = +QNaN
Inf  / Inf  = -QNaN, invalid
Inf  / QNaN = +QNaN, invalid
Inf  / SNaN = +QNaN
QNaN / 0.0  = +QNaN, invalid
QNaN / 1.0  = +QNaN, invalid
QNaN / Inf  = +QNaN, invalid
QNaN / QNaN = +QNaN, invalid
QNaN / SNaN = +QNaN, invalid
SNaN / 0.0  = +QNaN
SNaN / 1.0  = +QNaN
SNaN / Inf  = +QNaN
SNaN / QNaN = +QNaN, invalid
SNaN / SNaN = +QNaN
```

So why is the generated NaN sometimes negative and sometimes positive ? And why isn't there an `FE_INVALID` exception generated sometimes when a parameter is a `SNaN` ?
I know that there's no special use behind a negative or positive `NaN` because they both mean the same. But why is the `NaN` sometimes negative?

[EDIT]: I see that the negative NaN is delivered if the mantissas of both values are zero - why is that?

Comment: Re “So why is the generated NaN sometimes negative and sometimes positive ?”: That conclusion is incorrect. In each of the examples you show that has a generated NaN output, i.e., each of those in which neither input was a NaN, the output has a negative sign. In each example where an input you supplied was a NaN, the output has a positive sign, presumably because the NaN input you supplied had a positive sign. In each such case, the output NaN is not newly generated, merely copied from an input and, if that input was a signaling NaN, converted to a quiet NaN.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of IEEE-754 (2008) that governs the behavior observed reads as follows:

> **7.2 Invalid operation**
>
> The invalid operation exception is signaled if and only if there is no usefully definable result. [...]
> For operations producing results in floating-point format, the default result of an operation that signals the invalid operation exception shall be a quiet NaN that should provide some diagnostic information (see 6.2).
> These operations are:
> a) any general-computational or signaling-computational operation on a signaling NaN (see 6.2), except for some conversions (see 5.12)
> [...]
> e) division: division(0, 0) or division(∞, ∞)

On x86 hardware, signalling NaNs have the most significant bit of the *stored* significand cleared, while quiet NaNs have it set.

Any invalid operation not resulting from clause (a) above delivers a quiet NaN `INDEFINITE`: The most significant bit of its stored significand is set while all other significand bits are cleared, and the sign bit is set. For IEEE-754 `binary32` format, this results in the encoding `0xffc00000`, while for IEEE-754 `binary64` format, it results in the encoding `0xfff80000000000000`.

For an invalid operation resulting from clause (a), a signalling NaN input is "quietened" when being passed through by setting the most significant bit of the stored significand, making it into a quiet NaN with the payload otherwise preserved.

The following ISO-C99 demonstrates the behavior in more detail by showing the encoding of the operands:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
 
int test_division (float a, float b, float *r)
{
    fenv_t environment;
    int err, invalid = 0;
    err = fegetenv (&environment);
    feclearexcept (FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    *r = a / b;
    invalid = fetestexcept (FE_INVALID);
    err |= fesetenv (&environment);
    if (err) printf ("FAILED\n");
    return invalid;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}
 
int main()
{
    int invalid;
    uint32_t special[] =
    {
        0x00000000, // +0
        0x80000000, // -0
        0x7f800000, // +INF
        0xff800000, // -INF
        0x7f812345, // +SNAN
        0xff812345, // -SNAN
        0x7fc54321, // +QNAN
        0xffc54321  // -QNAN
    };
    int nbr_spec_ops = (int)(sizeof special / sizeof special[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbr_spec_ops; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nbr_spec_ops; j++) {
            uint32_t ia = special [i];
            uint32_t ib = special [j];
            float a = uint32_as_float (ia);
            float b = uint32_as_float (ib);
            float r;
            invalid = test_division (a, b, &r);
            uint32_t ir = float_as_uint32 (r);
            printf ("% 12.5e [%08x] / % 12.5e [%08x] = % 12.5e [%08x] %s\n",
                    a, ia, b, ib, r, ir, invalid ? "invalid" : "");
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The printing of NaNs and infinities is implementation defined. The output of the above program should look *similar* to this:

```
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /          inf [7f800000] =  0.00000e+00 [00000000] 
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /         -inf [ff800000] = -0.00000e+00 [80000000] 
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /          nan [7f812345] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /         -nan [ff812345] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /          nan [7fc54321] =          nan [7fc54321] 
 0.00000e+00 [00000000] /         -nan [ffc54321] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /          inf [7f800000] = -0.00000e+00 [80000000] 
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /         -inf [ff800000] =  0.00000e+00 [00000000] 
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /          nan [7f812345] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /         -nan [ff812345] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /          nan [7fc54321] =          nan [7fc54321] 
-0.00000e+00 [80000000] /         -nan [ffc54321] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
         inf [7f800000] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =          inf [7f800000] 
         inf [7f800000] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =         -inf [ff800000] 
         inf [7f800000] /          inf [7f800000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
         inf [7f800000] /         -inf [ff800000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
         inf [7f800000] /          nan [7f812345] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         inf [7f800000] /         -nan [ff812345] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
         inf [7f800000] /          nan [7fc54321] =          nan [7fc54321] 
         inf [7f800000] /         -nan [ffc54321] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
        -inf [ff800000] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =         -inf [ff800000] 
        -inf [ff800000] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =          inf [7f800000] 
        -inf [ff800000] /          inf [7f800000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
        -inf [ff800000] /         -inf [ff800000] =         -nan [ffc00000] invalid
        -inf [ff800000] /          nan [7f812345] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
        -inf [ff800000] /         -nan [ff812345] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -inf [ff800000] /          nan [7fc54321] =          nan [7fc54321] 
        -inf [ff800000] /         -nan [ffc54321] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
         nan [7f812345] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] /          inf [7f800000] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] /         -inf [ff800000] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] /          nan [7f812345] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] /         -nan [ff812345] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] /          nan [7fc54321] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
         nan [7f812345] /         -nan [ffc54321] =          nan [7fc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /          inf [7f800000] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /         -inf [ff800000] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /          nan [7f812345] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /         -nan [ff812345] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /          nan [7fc54321] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
        -nan [ff812345] /         -nan [ffc54321] =         -nan [ffc12345] invalid
         nan [7fc54321] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =          nan [7fc54321] 
         nan [7fc54321] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =          nan [7fc54321] 
         nan [7fc54321] /          inf [7f800000] =          nan [7fc54321] 
         nan [7fc54321] /         -inf [ff800000] =          nan [7fc54321] 
         nan [7fc54321] /          nan [7f812345] =          nan [7fc54321] invalid
         nan [7fc54321] /         -nan [ff812345] =          nan [7fc54321] invalid
         nan [7fc54321] /          nan [7fc54321] =          nan [7fc54321] 
         nan [7fc54321] /         -nan [ffc54321] =          nan [7fc54321] 
        -nan [ffc54321] /  0.00000e+00 [00000000] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
        -nan [ffc54321] / -0.00000e+00 [80000000] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
        -nan [ffc54321] /          inf [7f800000] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
        -nan [ffc54321] /         -inf [ff800000] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
        -nan [ffc54321] /          nan [7f812345] =         -nan [ffc54321] invalid
        -nan [ffc54321] /         -nan [ff812345] =         -nan [ffc54321] invalid
        -nan [ffc54321] /          nan [7fc54321] =         -nan [ffc54321] 
        -nan [ffc54321] /         -nan [ffc54321] =         -nan [ffc54321]
```